# Facing this error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"on web

Tags: node.js, express, iot, p5.js

I was trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hhEOGXcCvg&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6b36TzJidYfIYwTFEq3K5qH&index=2). At ‘10:40’ I see the blank page in the web browser.
My server is running like in the tutorial. When I checked the console of the webpage in the web browser. I saw that following errors:

[Error on web browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKslM.png)

[Server code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwHsP.png)

[p5.js sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pnIK.png)

[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IavGL.png)

[directory, sketch.js and index.html are in public folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1dhP.png)

How can I fix this?

**This question has also been posted [here](https://discourse.processing.org/t/facing-error-failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-404-not-found-in-web-browse-console/2433).**

Comment: @MohammadRaheem please see, I have updated the question with screenshot of all the codes

Comment: Hi, I change <script> line with `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` and it started working. I think there is some issue with relative addressing. How to fix that?

Comment: is there a problem with my addressing method? I have done relative addressing. can you please check index.html file photo that I have attached

Comment: can you share your folder/file structure.

Comment: please check "diectory" file I have attached in the question

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your js script in the public/assets folder. Then it should be served with correct mime type by the development server

Then reference it like below

```
<script src="/assets/scripts/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: There is was no assests folder. I made one folder named "assets" and put js script in it, but then also it is showing the same error in console.